# Python: Matching Index values to List values

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

Having an output of a list of lists containing index values of grouped elements for a (somewhat) corresponding list of tuples, how do I combine them into a list of grouped tuples?

```
data=[(1, 1), (1.5, 2), (3, 4), (5, 7), (3.5, 5), (4.5, 5), (3.5, 4.5)]
clusters=[[0], [], [4], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

These are sample values/groups. 
Example of what I'm asking about:

```
coordinates= [[(1,1)], [], [(3.5,5)], [(1.5,2),(3,4),(5,7),(4.5,5),(3.5,4.5)]]
```

I've tried list comprehensions and zips but when it comes to getting the value of [i] in clusters it gets confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a two-level list comprehension is what you want:

```
coordinates = [[data[index] for index in cluster] for cluster in clusters]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Confused me for a long time @Blckknght